# Read child node with XMLreader

Tags: c#

I have this XML file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <cteProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="1.04">
   <CTe>
   <emit>
       <xFant>DOW</xFant>
       <CNPJ>456789</CNPJ>
   </emit>
   <rem>
      <CNPJ>777777</CNPJ>
      <nCFOP>7101</nCFOP>
   </rem>
   </CTe>
   <protCTe versao="1.04">
   </cteProc>
```

To read this file I use this C# snippet:

```
    string 
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\Conhecimento\158_v01.04-rocCTe.xml");
        XmlNodeType type;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            type = reader.NodeType;
            if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "xFant")
                {  reader.Read(); XFant = reader.Value; textBox1.Text = XFant;} 

            if (reader.Name == "nCFOP")
                {  reader.Read(); nCFOP = reader.Value; textBox2.Text = nCFOP;} 
            }
        }
```

The code works very well, but doesn't work in the case of child nodes `<CNPJ>`; it only reads the first. How can I write this code to read the descendants? I have tried with something like `rem.CNPJ`.

From other  ask  question i see this code :

string CNPJ2,CNPJ3;

```
      XNamespace ns = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte";
        var todas = from ide in XElement.Load(@"C:\136_v01.04.xml").Descendants(ns + "ide")

                    select new { CNPJ1 = (string)ide.Element(ns + "CNPJ") };

        var emit  = from ide1 in XElement.Load(@"C:\136_v01.04.xml").Descendants(ns + "emit")

                    select new { CNPJ2 = (string)ide1.Element(ns + "CNPJ") };
```

but How to assign "todas"  to a single variabel like int CNPJ

Comment: Do you *have* to use XmlReader? If you could load the whole document and use LINQ to XML, it would be considerably less fiddly.

Comment: How is the code with LINQ to XML??

Comment: Well, you'd load the document with `XDocument.Load`, and then use the `Descendants` and `Elements` methods to query. If you haven't used LINQ to XML before, I suggest you read a tutorial, see how far you can get, and then post a new question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

If you use XDocument to read your xml

```
XDocument XMLDoc = XDocument.Load([path to xml file]);
```

you have a `Descendants(XName)` that you can use to get the node you are after.

```
XElement element = XMLDoc.Descendants("CNPJ").FirstOrDefault();
```